Calculating empty and NA values in R DataFrame with POSIXct columns
I'm working with a dataframe "trips_2023_tidy" in R, where two columns "started_at" and "ended_at" are in POSIXct format. My goal is to calculate the number of empty values "" and NA values in each column.
This is the code I attempted:
empty_count_tidy <- colSums(trips_2023_tidy == "", na.rm = TRUE)
na_count_tidy <- colSums(is.na(trips_2023_tidy))
total_count_tidy <- empty_count_tidy + na_count_tidy

# Creating a DataFrame with the results
available_data_tidy_df <- data.frame(
  empty_count = empty_count_tidy,
  na_count = na_count_tidy,
  total_missing = total_count_tidy,
  percentage_count = round(total_count_tidy/nrow(trips_2023_tidy)*100,2)
)

available_data_tidy_df$percentage_count <- paste(available_data_tidy_df$percentage_count, "%", sep=" ")
print(available_data_tidy_df)

However I encountered the following error:
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

You can find an extract of the dataframe at this link https://pastebin.com/VWiQExHk
This is the DF "trips_2023_tidy" structure:
'data.frame':   4331138 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ ride_id           : chr  "F96D5A74A3E41399" "13CB7EB698CEDB88" "BD88A2E670661CE5" "C90792D034FED968" ...
 $ rideable_type     : chr  "electric_bike" "classic_bike" "electric_bike" "classic_bike" ...
 $ started_at        : POSIXct, format: "2023-01-21 20:05:42" "2023-01-10 15:37:36" ...
 $ ended_at          : POSIXct, format: "2023-01-21 20:16:33" "2023-01-10 15:46:05" ...
 $ start_station_name: chr  "Lincoln Ave & Fullerton Ave" "Kimbark Ave & 53rd St" "Western Ave & Lunt Ave" "Kimbark Ave & 53rd St" ...
 $ start_station_id  : chr  "TA1309000058" "TA1309000037" "RP-005" "TA1309000037" ...
 $ end_station_name  : chr  "Hampden Ct & Diversey Ave" "Greenwood Ave & 47th St" "Valli Produce - Evanston Plaza" "Greenwood Ave & 47th St" ...
 $ end_station_id    : chr  "202480.0" "TA1308000002" "599" "TA1308000002" ...
 $ start_lat         : num  41.9 41.8 42 41.8 41.8 ...
 $ start_lng         : num  -87.6 -87.6 -87.7 -87.6 -87.6 ...
 $ end_lat           : num  41.9 41.8 42 41.8 41.8 ...
 $ end_lng           : num  -87.6 -87.6 -87.7 -87.6 -87.6 ...
 $ member_casual     : chr  "member" "member" "casual" "member" ...
 $ duration          : 'difftime' num  10.85 8.48 13.23 8.77 ...
  ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
 $ quarter           : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ day_of_week_number: num  6 2 1 7 4 2 7 3 3 5 ...
 $ day_of_week_name  : chr  "Saturday" "Tuesday" "Monday" "Sunday" ...

I need the DataFrame to be formatted as follows (example):
                   empty_count na_count total_missing percentage_count
ride_id                      0        0             0              0 %
rideable_type                0        0             0              0 %
started_at                   0        0             0              0 %
ended_at                     0        0             0              0 %
start_station_name      875716        0        875716          15.31 %
start_station_id        875848        0        875848          15.31 %
end_station_name        929202        0        929202          16.25 %
end_station_id          929343        0        929343          16.25 %
start_lat                    0        0             0              0 %
start_lng                    0        0             0              0 %
end_lat                      0     6990          6990           0.12 %
end_lng                      0     6990          6990           0.12 %
member_casual                0        0             0              0 %

Any suggestions on how to resolve this error and achieve the desired output format would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

You haven't shared your source data, so we are at a disadvantage...

I edited the post to include the DF structure

Please use dput.  It's easier for us to test your data.  As your data frame is large, please use dput(head(trips_2023_tidy, <n>), where <n> is a positive integer large enough to allow your problem to be reproduced.

I copied and pasted the extraction here and I updated the post accordingly

There's no as.POSIXlt in the code. Maybe it belongs to a section not included here.

But that is the exact error message that appears when I run the code.. I know there is no as.POSIXlt. Indeed I used as.POSIXct to convert the started_at and ended_at columns

Your data is correct? There's no NA nor "" on trips_2023_tidy here: https://pastebin.com/VWiQExHk.

Your code errors on the first line because colSums doesn't know how to interpret your POSIXct columns as blank strings "". I'm not sure the most elegant way to fix that, but I think you'd want empty_count_tidy to interleave zeroes for the non-character columns with the calculation you have for the character columns.

You'll get better and faster answers if you always provide sample/toy data - not just a link.
The linked dataset doesn't contain NAs or "". The toy data is at the end.
Here's my take:
# library(tidyverse)

# -----------------------
aux <- tibble(column = colnames(trips_2023_tidy))

aux$na_count         <- map_int(trips_2023_tidy, \(x) length(keep(x, is.na)))
aux$empty_count      <- map_int(trips_2023_tidy, \(x) length(keep(x[!is.na(x)], \(x) str_length(x) == 0)))
aux$total_missing    <- aux$na_count + aux$empty_count
aux$percentage_count <- 100 * aux$total_missing / nrow(aux)

The output:
> aux
# A tibble: 17 × 5
   column             na_count empty_count total_missing percentage_count
   <chr>                 <int>       <int>         <int>            <dbl>
 1 ride_id                   1           3             4            23.5 
 2 rideable_type             1           1             2            11.8 
 3 started_at                1           0             1             5.88
 4 ended_at                  2           0             2            11.8 
 5 start_station_name        1           0             1             5.88
 6 start_station_id          0           1             1             5.88
 7 end_station_name          0           0             0             0   
 8 end_station_id            0           0             0             0   
 9 start_lat                 2           0             2            11.8 
10 start_lng                 1           0             1             5.88
11 end_lat                   0           0             0             0   
12 end_lng                   0           0             0             0   
13 member_casual             2           2             4            23.5 
14 duration                  0           0             0             0   
15 quarter                   0           0             0             0   
16 day_of_week_number        0           0             0             0   
17 day_of_week_name          0           0             0             0  

Toy data
# Toy data (with NAs and "")
trips_2023_tidy <- structure(
  list(
    ride_id = c(
      NA, "41A2F326EE6EEE9D", "2FD700DE110A11A6", "", 
      "", "7191576D2E89102F", "689D537E5D034DA8", 
      "", "13CB7EB698CEDB88", "429CC513038C65E7"),
    
    rideable_type = c(
      "electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike", 
      "classic_bike", NA, "electric_bike", "electric_bike", 
      "electric_bike", "", "electric_bike"), 
    
    started_at = structure(
      c(1673336356, 1674198764, NA, 1672767154, 1673192010, 1673603458, 
        1672939688, 1673456605, 1673365056, 1674663109), 
      tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    
    ended_at = structure(
      c(1673336567, 1674198920, NA, 1672767716, 1673192527, 
        NA, 1672940604, 1673457214, 1673365565, 1674663750), 
      tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    
    start_station_name = c(
      "Komensky Ave & 55th St", "Lakeview Ave & Fullerton Pkwy", 
      "Elmwood Ave & Austin St", "Kimbark Ave & 53rd St", 
      "Hoyne Ave & Balmoral Ave", "Elmwood Ave & Austin St", 
      "Western Ave & Lunt Ave", "Avondale Ave & Irving Park Rd", 
      "Kimbark Ave & 53rd St", NA), 
    
    start_station_id = c(
      "347", "", "598", "TA1309000037", "655", "598", 
      "RP-005", "15624", "TA1309000037", "527"), 
    
    end_station_name = c(
      "Pulaski Rd & 51st St", "Hampden Ct & Diversey Ave", 
      "Elmwood Ave & Austin St", "Greenwood Ave & 47th St", 
      "Clark St & Elmdale Ave", "Elmwood Ave & Austin St", 
      "Valli Produce - Evanston Plaza", "Campbell Ave & Irving Park Rd", 
      "Greenwood Ave & 47th St", "Valli Produce - Evanston Plaza"), 
    
    end_station_id = c(
      "343", "202480.0", "598", "TA1308000002", "KA1504000148", 
      "598", "599", "439", "TA1308000002", "599"), 
    
    start_lat = c(
      41.79, 41.92588532, 42.025811076, NA, 
      41.979869246, 42.025716662, 42.0086135, 
      41.953178167, NA, 42.018966913), 
    
    start_lng = c(
      -87.72, -87.638976455, NA, -87.594747, -87.681931615, 
      -87.684132338, -87.6905225, -87.731947541, -87.594747, -87.69006753), 
    
    end_lat = c(
      41.8, 41.93, 42.025784, 41.809835, 41.9908604481256, 
      42.025784, 42.039742, 41.95, 41.809835, 42.039742), 
    
    end_lng = c(
      -87.72, -87.64, -87.684107, -87.599383, -87.6697236299515, 
      -87.684107, -87.699413, -87.69, -87.599383, -87.699413), 
    
    member_casual = c(
      NA, NA, "member", "member", "", "", 
      "casual", "casual", "member", "casual"), 
    
    duration = structure(
      c(3.52, 2.6, 0.93, 9.37, 8.62, 0.5, 15.27, 10.15, 8.48, 10.68), 
      class = "difftime", units = "secs"), 
    
    quarter = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    
    day_of_week_number = c(2, 5, 1, 2, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3), 
    
    day_of_week_name = c(
      "Tuesday", "Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Sunday", "Friday", 
      "Thursday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday")), 
  
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -10L))


Hi Adriano, thank you for your response. I apologize for thinking that using pastebin was a good idea; I've seen others do the same in other posts. I really appreciate your support, and I'll take the time to carefully study the code you provided.

@gorilla_ballz123 it’s really hard to beat a dput(head(df)) with just enough data to reproduce the problem! I have no problem with a public link, but again: you’ll get better and faster help providing some sample data.

@gorilla_ballz123 you can find map and keep reference and an excellent purrr pkg cheat sheet here: https://purrr.tidyverse.org/
